# Google app engine db model object object not iterable error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am at a loss to understand I am getting an error with the following code in Google App Engine.  I want to list out all the elements of a model object.  When I run the code I get the following error.  Can anyone explain to me why I am getting this error?

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evalentini\Desktop\Personal\Udacity Web Development Class\logintest\main.py", line 143, in get
    self.render("userlist.html", users=users)
  File "C:\Users\evalentini\Desktop\Personal\Udacity Web Development Class\logintest\main.py", line 73, in render
    self.write(render_str(template, **kw))
  File "C:\Users\evalentini\Desktop\Personal\Udacity Web Development Class\logintest\main.py", line 32, in render_str
    return t.render(params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Users\evalentini\Desktop\Personal\Udacity Web Development Class\logintest\templates\userlist.html", line 3, in top-level template code
    {% for user in users: %}
TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable
```

I've written requestHandler object (ListNames) which should list out the names (code below):

**class ListNames(BlogHandler):**

```
def get(self):
    users=User.all().get()
    self.render("userlist.html", users=users)
```

**which uses my User model:**

```
class User(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    pwd=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email=db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

**and a function called render to render page from jinja template:**

```
def render_str(template, **params):<br>
    t=jinja_env.get_template(template)
    <br>return t.render(params)
```

**Jinja Template Below:**

```
<html>

{% for user in users: %}
    <div style="{border: 1px solid; border-color: blue; padding: 1px;}">
        {{user.name}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

you are getting only 1 user

```
users=User.all().get()
```

this returns the the first entity

you need to use fetch() which returns a list of users

```
users=User.all().fetch(1000)
```

or pass in the query like:

```
users=User.all()
```

this last one is not the best option because it could return too many users and that would affect your apps performance or even worse.